# Adding MonitoredItems to an already existing subscription doesnt seem to work

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'm doing some exercises with the OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua package.

I successfully created a Session against Kepserver EX 6, and created a subscription with several MonitoredItems using the Random tags. 
The notification handler launches as expected and i can get the values, quality, etc..

However i dont seem to be capable of adding a MonitoredItem after the subscription has been created. I get no errors and the MonitoredItem is in the list of the Subscription, but my handler is never called.

Sample Code for the adding part:

```
Session s = Program.s;
List<Subscription> subs = s.Subscriptions.ToList();
Subscription sub = subs.FirstOrDefault();
var m = new MonitoredItem(s.DefaultItem) { DisplayName = displayName, StartNodeId = startNodeID };
m.Notification += handler;
sub.AddItem(m);
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: I don't know how exactly the implementation is written, but it has the standard compliant behavior. The client-side subscription has its server-side counterpart which cant be changed while it is "working". You can create a new one or have multiple in parallel (e.g. one for all alarm event and one for the values you are currently displaying). The targeted scenario is that of the SCADA "screen": it has a limited number of things to display at once: when you switch the screen, you subscribe to the tags you have on the new screen while disposing the subscription you had for the screen you close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call ApplyChanges() on the subscription, after you are finished adding, deleting or modifying the monitored items.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Somehow i missed that it worked while trying other stuff. Thank you very much!